# unable to run for loop in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a for loop but to no success.
what I am trying to do is,I have a sheet with 1 in the entire column, I need to find the first row in which 1 appears and then blank out 25 cells from it.

```
 var values = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        for(var i = 0;i<values.length; i++){    
    if(values[i][0] == 1 ){
  Logger.log(i);
  break;
}  }
  for(var j = i;j<i+24; j++){
    sheet.getRange(j,3).setValue("");}
```

however, nothing happens.
I do not know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to find the first element in the column that is `1` and then clear the content of `25` cells after that in the same column.

You don't need a `for` loop to achieve your goal. You can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

- Since you are interested only in one column, grab that column only and use it as an 1D array; [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) will convert the 2D array to 1D array:

  `sh.getRange(start_row,3,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();`
- Then use `findIndex` to find the first `1` in this array:

  `const index=values.findIndex(v=>v==1) + start_row;`

  and add `2` (`start_row`) since you start counting from the second row.
- Finally, you don't need a `for` loop to clear the content of the cells. You can select the desired range and clear the content with [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) in one go:

  `sh.getRange(index,3,25).clearContent();`

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // use the name of your sheet here
 const start_row = 2;
 const values = sh.getRange(start_row,3,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
 const index=values.findIndex(v=>v==1) + start_row;
 sh.getRange(index,3,25).clearContent();
}
```

same solution in the 3 lines of code if that matters to you:

```
function myFunction() {
 const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // use the name of your sheet here
 const index = sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().findIndex(v=>v==1) + 2;
 sh.getRange(index,3,25).clearContent();
}
```